# SoftDeleted child entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have a project built on Symfony + API Platform + Doctrine, and I've recently implemented the Gedmo SoftDelete feature. Everything is running smoothly, but I've encountered a situation where I need to address the following issue:

I have an entity called Order with its own properties, and it references the OrderItem entity. The problem arises when I perform a soft delete on the OrderItem entity; it causes an error when I try to retrieve the Order entity. Is it possible to configure it in a way that when I retrieve the parent entity, I can see the association to the child, but when I subsequently list all OrderItems, I don't see the soft-deleted ones?

Comment: You could proof custom repository function that select joined entities, and before disable softdeleteable filter.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe [symfony docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/softdeleteable-filter.html) can help you:

```
$filters = $em->getFilters();
$filters->disable('softdeleteable');
```